# How to remove value from Dynamics Entity using SDK library in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I'm trying to find out how to remove an option set attribute using a console application, the closest I've come is to assign -1 to the option set value, since when I do this in the Dynamics Interface it will appear no value was selected for that field. Here is my code so far:

```
        var employees= DataAdapter.GetEmployees(); //List of Entities

        var employee1 = participants[0];

        ((OptionSetValue)employee1 [Constants.Attributes.GENDER]).Value = -1;


        DataAdapter.UpdateParticipant(employee1);
```

The Data Adapter Update is simply:

```
           CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

            IOrganizationService _orgService;
            _orgService = (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;

            using (OrganizationServiceContext orgSvcContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(_orgService))
            {
                orgSvcContext.Attach(Entity);
                orgSvcContext.UpdateObject(Entity);
                orgSvcContext.SaveChanges();
```

I'm syncing data from Dynamics and another source, that's why I prefer that if for example there is no gender in the source, that if I'm updating the destination (Dynamics Solution), to be able to not have the attribute at all instead of -1, since in the future comparing -1 to nothing would be a mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to explicitly set the gender attribute with no value simply assign NULL to the attribute

> employee1[Constants.Attributes.GENDER] = null;

Comment: After the update if I retrieve the Entity again it will have one less attribute,in this case the Gender Option Set Value. This is exactly the behavior I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be:

```
employee1.Attributes.Remove(Constants.Attributes.GENDER);
```

Comment: Nice, does this give the same results as above when you explicitly set to null?